# How to use JSON with react-ace?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, react-ace

Im using [react-ace](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace) and trying the readme example with java syntax. Works great. But I can't seem to set it to JSON.

#### Java works

```js
import AceEditor from "react-ace";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-java";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-github";

<AceEditor
    mode="java"
    theme="github"
    name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
    editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
/>
```

#### JSON does not work?

```js
import AceEditor from "react-ace";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-json";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-github";

<AceEditor
    mode="json"
    theme="github"
    name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
    editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
/>
```

#### The error

> Refused to execute script from '...../worker-json.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable.
> (anonymous) @ 2f896707-86be-497a-93b2-e1711942d7c7:1
> 2f896707-86be-497a-93b2-e1711942d7c7:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at '...../worker-json.js' failed to load.

How to use JSON?

Comment: Do you have a minimal reproducible repo?

Answer (score 8):

Try to setOption `useWorker: false`

```
      <AceEditor
        mode="json"
        theme="github"
        onChange={onChange}
        name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
        editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
        setOptions={{
          useWorker: false
        }}
      />
```

Comment: This turns annotations off

Comment: This turns annotations off as specified. But I found this helpful hint that works with annotations and doesn't throw those errors:

You have to add this before 'react-ace' ->
import 'ace-builds';
import 'ace-builds/webpack-resolver';

For my setup, I now can see errors for JSON and don't have to disable workers.

Comment: So here is a workaround with working annotations, webpack 5, and TS type fixes as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74180795/5282202

Answer (score 6):

From my understanding, you would need to do either way to resolve the worker problem.

- Import this `ace-builds/webpack-resolver`:

```js
import AceEditor from "react-ace";

import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-json";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-github";

import 'ace-builds/webpack-resolver';
```

- Use `file-loader` to load `worker-json` file & then configure ace worker:

```js
import AceEditor from "react-ace";

import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-json";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-github";

import ace from "ace-builds";

// `webpack` would return the url for `worker-json.js`
// then we use it to configure `ace`
import jsonWorkerUrl from "file-loader!ace-builds/src-noconflict/worker-json";

ace.config.setModuleUrl("ace/mode/json_worker", jsonWorkerUrl);
```

Comment: Both these methods give: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope'

Comment: Can you share the minimal reproducible repo? So I can have a look for you (looks like a specific case since things work fine on my end)

Comment: I will need to set that up! Here is full repo: https://github.com/ajthinking/data-story/blob/master/src/resources/js/components/modals/NodeWidgetModal.js

Comment: I'm not sure how to run your client independently. I tried `yarn hot` but nothing seems to work

Comment: file-upload is deprecated in Webpack 5, so please consider my research on that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74180795/5282202

Answer (score 1):

One way I made it work was to use **mode/json5** (json5 is a superset of json so it work normal) instead of **mode/json**.
Looking at the some github issue on this problem it seems to have few good options to be able to use mode/json.

- not every project works to import the worker via webpack/file-loader
- using the webpack-resolver makes the build to big

Some issues on ace own library and some componentes of some other frameworks that use ace.

- [Vue ace component](https://github.com/CarterLi/vue3-ace-editor/issues/12)
- [Ace](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/3913)
- [Agular ace component](https://github.com/fxmontigny/ng2-ace-editor/issues/92)

Answer (score 1):

For those searching how to implement workers now, when `file-upload` is deprecated with Webpack 5 `asset/resource`.

webpack config:

```js
rules: [
  {
      test: /ace-builds.*\/worker-.*$/,
      type: "asset/resource"
  },
],
```

component:

```
import AceEditor from "react-ace";
import { config } from "ace-builds";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-javascript";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-github";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/ext-language_tools";
import jsWorkerUrl from "ace-builds/src-noconflict/worker-javascript";
config.setModuleUrl("ace/mode/javascript_worker", jsWorkerUrl);
```

To fix the typescript "no module declaration" error, just add the `global.d.ts` file to your `src` folder:

```
declare module "ace-builds/src-noconflict/worker-javascript";
```